# Excel me muestra una alerta de formato o contenido incompatible - Archivo xls generado con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

Estoy generando un archivo **xls** con **JavaScript** y me descarga bien pero al momento de abrirlo me muestra este mensaje:
[image: Mensaje]

Este archivo lo estoy generando con este código:

```js
 function Exportar(){
        var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
        , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
        , base64 = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
        , format = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

        var table = 'order_table-col';
        var name = 'Usuaios';

        if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
        var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
        //window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.download = "Reporte de Usuarios.xls";
        link.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
        link.click();
}
```

```html
                      <input type="button" onclick="Exportar()" value="Exportar a Excel"  class="btn btn-info">
                      <table class="table" id="order_table-col">
                        <thead class="text-primary">
                          <tr>  
                            <th class="click-order">Agencia</th>
                            <th class="click-order">Cliente</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Responsable</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Código de orden</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Fecha</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Horas</th>
                          </tr>  
                        </thead>
                      </table>
```

He intentado cambiar la extensión a **xlsx** pero no me abre el archivo, entonces no se como solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Una manera rapida es usando el siguiente metodo, solo que pruebalo fuera de este ambiente por cuestiones de seguridad no abre el recurso.

```js
$("#btnExportar").click(function (e) {
    $(this).attr({
        'download': "MiExcel.xls",
            'href': 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent( $('#divData').html())
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button"  id="btnExportar"   value="Exportar a Excel"  class="btn btn-info">
                    <div id="divData">
                      <table class="table" id="order_table">
                        <thead class="text-primary">
                          <tr>  
                            <th class="click-order">Agencia</th>
                            <th class="click-order">Cliente</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Responsable</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Código de orden</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Fecha</th>  
                            <th class="click-order">Horas</th>
                          </tr>  
                        </thead>
                      </table>
                      </div>
```